# How to save in-memory sqlite to disk periodically

Tags: sqlite, go

I have a program using sqlite as in-memory db and I would like to save the database to disk periodically. I saw [this](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) on the sqlite documentation site and I wonder if there are go APIs for such task.

Comment: What you *should* be looking into is if go's sqlite bindings support the [backup API](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html). WAL mode is completely meaningless for in memory databases and isn't a backup mechanism anyways.

Comment: If you want the database on disk, why do you use an in-memory connection to begin with?

Comment: @gyuaisdfaasf what did you end up using out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can issue the [`.dump` command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#converting_an_entire_database_to_an_ascii_text_file) and store the results in a file?

It looks like [schollz/sqlite3dump](https://github.com/schollz/sqlite3dump) may do exactly what you want.